# SharePoint 2013 site collection TLS 1.0 migration to TLS 1.2

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, tls

We have multiple site collections hosted in SharePoint 2013.

We are asked to change the TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.2 for specific site collection as per the local country security compliance.

Is it possible to change the TLS version to specific site collection in SharePoint farm or should we require to update the all the servers & SQL to TLS 1.2

Answer (score 1):

here is described [Enable TLS and SSL support in SharePoint 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-and-ssl-support-in-sharepoint-2013) and there is no option to do this only for one Site Collection.

Comment: I am not using secure channel for communication between WFE and SQL . So if we enable TLS 1.2 in only sharepoint web servers along with existing TLS 1.0,  will the site deliver with TLS 1.2 in client browsers?